# How drop duplicates rows and keep first in dataframes dict using .keys() ? Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm debugging some code, I noticed that I am trying to remove the rows from the applied ones keeping the first one I am using:

```
for key in NewDict.keys():
    NewDict[key] = NewDict[key].drop_duplicates(['begin','end','duration'], keep = 'first')
```

I don't have **duplicate rows deleted in this method** .

I think I can't delete the rows dupplied and keep the first in method **because of the dictionary** but I don't know how to do it.

Here a piece of my DataFrameDict.keys():

```
u'WT4':
    date_time                       begin                       end                         duration
0   2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716  2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268  156.218
1   2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327  2019-10-21 07:42:02.222821  118.987
2   2019-10-21 07:42:02.222821      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327  2019-10-21 07:42:02.222821  118.987
3   2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716  2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268  156.218
4   2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657      2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657  2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114  27.534

u'CO'
    date_time                       begin                       end                         duration
0   2020-03-19 15:21:56.276133      2020-03-19 15:21:56.276133  2020-03-19 15:21:58.687318  2.411
1   2020-03-19 15:21:58.687318      2020-03-19 15:21:56.276133  2020-03-19 15:21:58.687318  2.411
2   2020-03-19 15:22:25.718375      2020-03-19 15:22:25.718375  2020-03-19 15:22:32.937153  7.219
3   2020-03-19 15:22:32.937153      2020-03-19 15:22:25.718375  2020-03-19 15:22:32.937153  7.219
4   2020-03-19 15:22:59.061943      2020-03-19 15:22:59.061943  2020-03-19 15:23:05.870261  6.808
```

The expected result:

```
u'WT4':
    date_time                       begin                       end                         duration
0   2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716      2019-10-21 07:39:26.356716  2019-10-21 07:42:02.574268  156.218
1   2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327      2019-10-21 07:40:03.235327  2019-10-21 07:42:02.222821  118.987
4   2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657      2019-10-21 07:42:52.299657  2019-10-21 07:43:19.834114  27.534

u'CO'
    date_time                       begin                       end                         duration
0   2020-03-19 15:21:56.276133      2020-03-19 15:21:56.276133  2020-03-19 15:21:58.687318  2.411
2   2020-03-19 15:22:25.718375      2020-03-19 15:22:25.718375  2020-03-19 15:22:32.937153  7.219
4   2020-03-19 15:22:59.061943      2020-03-19 15:22:59.061943  2020-03-19 15:23:05.870261  6.808
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, your code words fine. What version of pandas are you running?

Comment: this is just a piece of my real df. Pandas version: 1.0.5

Comment: you have right, it's working, I find the bug. It is in when I specify which column, I needed to add more columns.